# Cargar archivo csv spark 2.3.0 para analizarlo con k-means

Tags: csv, scala, apache-spark

Soy nuevo utilizando Apache Spark, version 2.3.0. Me estoy basando en el código de ejemplo que viene en la página de Spark para poder utilizar el algoritmo k-means. Realizo el ejemplo que se muestra a continuación y lo corre perfectamente, pero al intentar utilizarlo con archivo csv salen los errores mostrados en la imagen.

Necesito saber qué estoy haciendo mal, si es la forma de cargar el archivo o modificar el código del algoritmo.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.ClusteringEvaluator

// Loads data
val dataset = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_kmeans_data.txt")

// Trains a k-means model
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1L)
val model = kmeans.fit(dataset)

// Make predictions
val predictions = model.transform(dataset)

// Evaluate clustering by computing Silhouette score
val evaluator = new ClusteringEvaluator()

val silhouette = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
println(s"Silhouette with squared euclidean distance = $silhouette")

// Shows the result
println("Cluster Centers: ")
model.clusterCenters.foreach(println)
```

[image: Algoritmok-means con archivo csv]

[image: Archivo csv]

Comment: Necesitamos ver algo de los datos que empleas para poder repetir el cálculo y ver dónde falla. Pero algo me dice que tu problema es que ninguna columna tiene por nombre `features` que es el nombre por defecto que busca para la entrada de `KMeans`.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Hola compañero disculpa ya puse el archivo que  quiero emplear, en que parte del código se modifica lo que me dijiste

Comment: Hubiera sido mejor tener los datos en un formato que pudiera probar y darte una respuesta. Por lo que veo, tienes 123 campos. Te falta elegir qué campos serán las dimensiones de entrada del cálculo. [VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler) puede serte útil. Te dejo un [tutorial](https://www.zylk.net/en/web-2-0/blog/-/blogs/kmeans-con-zeppelin-y-spark) que puede darte pistas.

Comment: @ChemaCortes creo no se puede cargar archivos en la pregunta pero lo descargue de este enlace http://www.issste.gob.mx/datosabiertos/censodiscapacidad.csv, me seria de mucha ayuda este ejemplo ya que estoy empezando a usar spark

Answer (score 0):

deberias usar VectorAssembler para poder cargar todas las variables que se pueden predecir, en tu caso el error es no tener la columna features.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler

Te dejo un ejemplo usando tu mismo ejemplo, fijate que he utilizado spark para cargar el csv, hice un cast de las column para poder hacer la transformacion se requiere numeros.

```
val df = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true") //first line in file has headers
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .load("pathCSV.csv")

df.show(false)
df.printSchema()

val df2 = df.withColumn("num", col("NUMERO").cast(IntegerType)) //casteo para predecir
  .withColumn("hombr", col("HOMBRES").cast(IntegerType))
  .withColumn("mujer", col("MUJERES").cast(IntegerType))

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("num", "hombr", "mujer"))
  .setOutputCol("features") //columna necesaria

val output = assembler.transform(df2)
println("Assembled num 'NUMERO', 'hombr', 'mujer' to vector column 'features'")
output.select("features", "HOMBRES").show(false)

// Trains a k-means model
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1L)
val model = kmeans.fit(output)

// Make predictions
val predictions = model.transform(output)
```